# How do I put my taxonomy image in a div as a background image?

Tags: html, wordpress

I added images to specific text with acf and taxonomy , this is my code for it

```
                      $types = get_terms( array(
                          'taxonomy' => 'answer',
                          'hide_empty' => false,
                      ) );

                      foreach($types as $type) {

                          $image = get_field('featured_image', 'answer_' . $type->term_id . '' );

                          if ( has_term( $type->term_id, 'answer')) {
                              echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" /> ';
                          }
                      }

                      ?>
```

Now I would like to have these images for `<div class="description"> *results are here* </div>`

I tried with `<div style="background-image: url("<?php echo$image ['url'] ?>");">`  but that doesnt seem to work.

And how would i go about styling these images ? CSS?

This happens when I try J.Doe answer - [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEmvl.jpg)

Now after I try the code j.Doe edited [this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ONp7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Both methods should work fine.
However, you missed one detail:
The code

```
<div style="background-image: url("<?php echo$image ['url'] ?>");">
```

requires you to set the dimensions of the `DIV` because otherwise your `DIV` has a `height` and `width` of 0px and therefore no `background-image` is displayed.
So enhance the code to the following:

```
<div style="background: url(<?php echo$image ['url'] ?>) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover; height: 300px; width: 300px;">
```

This should give you a 300x300px `DIV` with the `background-image` set. You need to adjust the aspect ratio to your image.

The code

```
<img src="<?php $image['url'] ?>" />
```

should work out of the box. Of course you also need to style your image to the desired expectations.

Comment: Hey it just shows ![this and doesnt show the image ](https://imgur.com/a/EXxXqHD).

Comment: Please do not link to third party providers. Instead embed the image to your question. Then I will have a look at it.

Comment: Did it you can check it now

Comment: I corrected my code. You are not allowed to have two double quotes inside of each other. Please try without double quotes inside `url()`

Comment: That didnt help, i edited my question with a new image

Comment: Well but you did check that `$image['url']` contains the desired value right? It seems to be empty. Please do a var_dump($image) and show the output.

Comment: I even corrected it to` backgound-image ` and the same happens

Comment: Yes, that makes sense if the key `url` in the `$image` array is empty.
Please do what I told you in the comment before.

Comment: okay, i forgot i had set in the for each `echo '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" /> ';` to `$feat_image = '<img src="' . $image['url'] . '" /> '; ` and it does display when i `echo $feat_image` but not when i put it in `<div  style="background-image: url(<?php echo$feat_image  ?>); `

Comment: Your PHP code has as it seems lots of errors. Please run it through a syntax checker and have a look at it again. I cannot help you with one line code snippets that are not in any context.